# Moving from Maven to Gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle

Currently I am working on android project which is built using maven. Now I need to move from maven to gradle. Can I manually add `build.gradle` file in my project root and start just like that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the layout of the files for java projects are usually the same, Gradle intentionally used the same file tree conventions than Maven for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I got my pom.xml file converted to build.gradle

I just followed the following steps:

i. First install gradle (For MAC users: brew install gradle)
ii. Go to project root from terminal and enter the command --> gradle init

Now go to your project and you can see build.gradle file.